# String to json conversion issue

Tags: java, json

I am trying to convert a string to `JSONObject` object using the below code,but i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to net.sf.json.JSONObject .
```

Source:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
    public static void run(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        System.out.println("in run--");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("here");
        String json = "{\"task\": \"com.ge.dbt.workers.surveytoexcel.worker.SurveyWorker\",\"prod_id\": 12345,\"survey_id\": 5666,\"person_id\": 18576567,\"req_date\": \"12\12\2012\"}";
        JSONObject jsonObj;
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = parser.parse(json);

        jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        run(jsonObj);
    }
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've imported `JSONObject` from the wrong package.  Change this line:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```

to this:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the following solution, ***You don't even have to bother about a parser***...

The Problem here is that u're trying to cast a object of type `org.json.simple.JSONObject` to `net.sf.json.JSONObject`. You might wanna try The package `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`. that is enough to do all the required things.

**Simple Example**:

First, Prepare a String:

`String jStr = "{\"name\":\"Fred\",\"Age\":27}";`

Now, to parse the `String` Object, U just have to pass the String to the `JSONObject();` constructor method

`JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jStr);`

That should do it and voila! You have a JSONObject.
Now you can play with it as u please.

How So Simple ain't it?

**The Modified version of the Code might look like**:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
```

```
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;
public static void run(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    System.out.println("in run-- "+jsonObject.getInt("person_id"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("here");
    String json = "{\"task\": \"com.ge.dbt.workers.surveytoexcel.worker.SurveyWorker\",\"prod_id\": 12345,\"survey_id\": 5666,\"person_id\": 18576567,\"req_date\": \"12\12\2012\"}";
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    run(jsonObj);
}
```

with JSON, It's SssOooooooo simple

Comment: -1: `net.sf.json.JSONObject` doesn't have a `String` constructor.  http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: I'm realllly sorry! I take it back. Oh my bad! I just confused `org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject` with `net.sf.json.JSONObject` . Thanks anyway for pointing that out. @David Grant is correct and I'm wrong. Guys sorry for the wrong information.